# Android: Adding data to Intent fails to load Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a widget that supposed to call an Activity of the main app when the user clicks on widget body. My setup works for a single widget instance but for a second instance of the same widget the PendingIntent gets reused and as result the vital information that I'm sending as extra gets overwritten for the 1st instance. So I figured that I should pass widget ID as `Intent` data however as soon as I add `Intent#setData` I would see in the log that 2 separate Intents are appropriately fired but the Activity fails to pick it up so basically Activity will not come up and nothing happens (no error or warning ether)
Here's how the activity is setup in the Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsView" 
         android:label="@string/search_results"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="bostone.android.search.RESULTS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here's code that is setup for handling the click

```
Intent di = new Intent("bostone.android.search.RESULTS");
di.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
// if line below is commented out - the Activity will start
di.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.EMPTY, widgetId));
di.putExtra("URL", url);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetContent, 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, di, 0));
```

The main app and the widget are packaged as 2 separate APK each in its own package and Manifest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a `<data>` tag in your `<intent-filter>` in order for the intent you are firing to match the intent-filter you have registered.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Also using Uri.EMPTY may be a problem.  I'd create your own Uri scheme, so that your setData() call looks something like:

```
di.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("droidln://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
```

and your intent-filter would look like:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="bostone.android.search.RESULTS" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="droidln"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Oh! But of course - silly me! Thanks @mbaird - it works perfectly now

Comment: @Mark B I have a similar use case.  I understand your answer except the contents of Uri.parse.  I see the scheme defined in the data element, but what is "...://widget/id/"?