# LocalBroadcastManager not working for intent which has data attribute

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have been stuck here over half a day for not receiving the broadcast message in Receiver.

Here I am sending a broadcast message with data attribute set. When I do like this, message not received at receiver.

```
Intent intent  = new Intent("some.action");
intent.putExtras(receivedIntent.getExtras());
intent.setData(receivedIntent.getData());
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But when I don't set the data attribute, message received as normal.

```
Intent intent  = new Intent("some.action");
intent.putExtras(receivedIntent.getExtras());
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Is setting data to intent really a problem or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

[setData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData(android.net.Uri)) points to a location (could be for example a file). I'm pretty sure you intended to use [putExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)).

```
Intent i = new Intent("some.action");   
i.putExtra("Variable name", "Content to send");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

As an argument, `setData` expects a Uri so if that really is what you want, there's something else wrong with the code.

> Uri: The Uri of the data this intent is now targeting.
>   This value may be null.

Comment: Hi @hankide,
Thanks for your answer.
I want to forward the received intent with a new destination with same extras and data. That's why I am setting data attribute.

Comment: @vijay So, you're using setData succesfully in the previous step and this code here is the forwarding part that doesn't work? Could you update the code to include the first step too?

Comment: @vijay Do you have the data specification in your intent filter as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618813/6625726?

Comment: Hi @hankide, 
Thanks for your reply.
I have updated the actual code.

Comment: @vijay Did you see my last comment about the intent filter? Can't think of anything else that could be wrong.